# Applying multiple classes to ReactJS component

Tags: reactjs

I need to apply multiple classes to a React component without installing anything extra. Is that possible?

```
<Component id="test1" className="blue-text kps hide-on-small-and-down" />
```

I also tried

```
<Component id="test1" className={`blue-text kps hide-on-small-and-down`} />
```

But nothing works.

I have been searching for hours but did not find anything that does not require extra installations.
Please do not downvote without explaining why. 
Thank you

Comment: Either way should work, you can see an example here https://codesandbox.io/s/8y6vxok3yl - do you have some more context to see why it might not be working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a `className` directly to a component, it is passed to that instance of the component as a prop accessible inside the component as `this.props.className`, and it's up to you to apply that class to *actual* DOM elements inside your component.

Remember that a React component is not an *actual* DOM element, but a higher-order logical construct that will be translated into one or several DOM elements (while also adding behavior, etc.). CSS classes only apply to DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

I see a wrong usage of className in your code. **className** stands for standard **class** attribute in standard html. Quoting the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html).

"To specify a CSS class, use the className attribute. This applies to all **regular DOM and SVG elements** like , , and others."

It is for regular DOM and SVG elements where you can use **className** attribute.

Example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42n375s9/)

```
<div className="one two three"> 
    This is the {this.props.name}
</div>
```

Example usage.

Adding another point I don't think using **className** to pass props down to child elements is a good idea since the **className** is serving a purpose here.